# Sublime text sass build system: compressed with comments

Tags: css, wordpress, sass, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have two sass build systems installed in my sublime text: sass and sass compressed. The problem is that sass compressed delete all my comments what is pretty bad for the native wordpress style because the first comment block is needed there.

Is it possible to create a build system for compressed css that preserves comments?

The current sass compressed build system looks like this:

```
{

    "cmd": ["sass", "--update", "$file:${file_path}/${file_base_name}.css", "--stop-on-error", "--no-cache", "--style", "compressed"],

    "selector": "source.sass, source.scss",
    "line_regex": "Line ([0-9]+):",

    "osx":
    {
        "path": "/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
    },

    "windows":
    {
        "shell": "true"
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the compiler you used but if you use [Prepros](https://prepros.io/), there's an option to preserve comments amongst a few other options to set the amount of compression. It's worth taking a look if you've never heard of it, saved me lots of work when working with sass.

Comment: Thanks but i want to use it from within sublime text. My Compiler is this one: https://github.com/jaumefontal/SASS-Build-SublimeText2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got a pretty easy workaround. Newer versions of sass supporting the /*! Important comment */ syntax and leaving out this part in the compilation.

So simply add that ! to your comment block of the wordpress style.